# Selected Datagrid row shows black box around first cell instead of blue highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've had the problem for awhile where an update to the Itemsource of my Datagrid resulted in the selectedItem being set to null.  I've been googling like mad and finally have something where the desired row stays selected, but I'm getting a black box around the first cell of the row instead of the full row being highlighted.  Clicking up/down arrow keys will change the selected row and the new row will be highlighted as expected.

Here is my XAML:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredSimResults}" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsReadOnly="True"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPdf}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
              Visibility="{Binding Path=IsNotPopulating}" Margin="5,0" Name="PdfList"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBold}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="OnRowSelected"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
    public SimulationGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PdfList.Items);
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCollectionView).CollectionChanged += OnItemSourceChanged;
    }

    private void OnItemSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_index == null) return;
        object item = _index;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
        {
            PdfList.SelectedItem = item;
            PdfList.ScrollIntoView(item);
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)PdfList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }));
    }

    private void OnRowSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _index = ((DataGridRow)sender).Item;
    }
```

EDIT:
I'm binding to this:

```
    public List<SimResult> FilteredSimResults
    {
        get
        {
            List<SimResult> filteredResults = new List<SimResult>();
            if (!Populating && SimResults != null)
            {
                foreach (SimResult result in SimResults)
                {
                    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterKey) || result.PatientId.ToLower().Contains(FilterKey.ToLower()))
                        && (ShowingHiddenSims != result.IsVisible))
                    {
                        filteredResults.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            return SimSortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending
                ? filteredResults.OrderByDescending(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(SimSortColumn).GetValue(o)).ToList()
                : filteredResults.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(SimSortColumn).GetValue(o)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The full list is kept in memory (SimResults), but it has several thing that can modify the list, so only the modified list is sent to the binding.  So, every time it is modified, the full list is modified.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what the DataGrid is binding to. You don't have a Code Behind reference to FilteredSimResults which is the ItemsSource of your DataGrid. Is that an ObservableCollection<T>? Also how is the data being edited? Are you replacing all the values in the grid. Are you replacing the one being selected? Are you leaving the object in the List and just editing the properties etc?

Comment: I've added details about what I'm binding to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each update completely replaces your List of items.

When FilteredSimResults returns it returns a completely different List object each time, which isn't a nice way to handle this sort of thing.

If you want to update data in code behind or in your ViewModel (if you use MVVM) you should be using an ObservableCollection, that is exactly what it was made for.

```
public ObservableCollection<SimResult> SimResults { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SimResult>();
```

Binding to that in your XAML is like so:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="319" Width="517" ItemsSource="{Binding SimResults}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="PatientId" Binding="{Binding PatientId}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Once you have that any changes to your ObservableCollection will be reflected in the Grid. One thing to note is that your SimsResults Class must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

You will still have this issue for deletions or if you completely remove an item, but you should NEVER remove an item, just change it's properties.

Comment: I'm not really seeing how to make an ObservableCollection do any of the filtering or sorting that my current implementation does.

Comment: For filtering, ordering, and grouping what you want is a CollectionViewSource. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx

So you make your collection an ObservableCollection then you feed that into a CollectionViewSource and have your View bind to the CollectionViewSource. Then you can filter, sort, group whatever you want.